# Find files of commit A that have changed compared to commit B with git?

Tags: git, git-diff

I am looking for something like "git diff --name-only B A", but limited to files contained in commit A. Or, in other words, I need a list of all files changed with commit A (excluding history) that are not the same as in commit B (including history).

Is there an easy way to do this in git?

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`--diff-filter` option](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-diff.html#_options) to do this.  To find only the files that are modified (rather than deleted or added, say) between `A` and `B`, you could do:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M B A
```

Comment: Won't this still find files that where modified by another commit than A?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand what you mean, but to clarify: this command will take the set of files contains in commit A, the set of files in commit B, and then show the list of files that exist in both of those sets and which are different in commit A and commit B.